# MS Graph - Access Reviews - recurrenceType Dependency?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am able to create an access review using this JSON:

```
{
    "displayName": "Test-review-2 Group Membership Review",
    "startDateTime":"2020-01-15T00:00:11.111Z",
    "endDateTime":"2020-04-04T00:00:11.111Z",
    "reviewedEntity":
    {
        "id": "f4b4b660-a6c2-4b1f-bb16-75f81432a63e"
    },
    "reviewerType" : "entityOwners",
    "businessFlowTemplateId": "6e4f3d20-c5c3-407f-9695-8460952bcc68",
    "description":"Access Review for the AAD group:Test-review-2(f4b4b660-a6c2-4b1f-bb16-75f81432a63e)",
    "settings":
    {    
        "mailNotificationsEnabled":true,
        "remindersEnabled": true,
        "justificationRequiredOnApproval":true,
        "autoReviewEnabled":false,
        "activityDurationInDays":365,
        "autoApplyReviewResultsEnabled":true,
        "accessRecommendationsEnabled":false,
        "recurrenceSettings":
        {
            "recurrenceType":"onetime",
            "recurrenceEndType":"occurrences",
            "durationInDays":7,
            "recurrenceCount":3
        },
        "autoReviewSettings":{
            "notReviewedResult":"Approve"
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the recurrenceType to "weekly", I suddenly get an error:

```
Unhandled exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Message: An error has occurred.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: c1ba20d2-4fbb-45e4-ac89-a7f0ebb650ba
        date: 2020-01-14T19:54:42
ClientRequestId: c1ba20d2-4fbb-45e4-ac89-a7f0ebb650ba
)
 ---> Status Code: InternalServerError
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Message: An error has occurred.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: c1ba20d2-4fbb-45e4-ac89-a7f0ebb650ba
        date: 2020-01-14T19:54:42
ClientRequestId: c1ba20d2-4fbb-45e4-ac89-a7f0ebb650ba
```

I have looked through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accessreview?view=graph-rest-beta), and can't understand why.. Is there a dependent property I'm missing?

Comment: Try removing `durationInDays`, it is likely conflicting with `weekly`

Comment: Unfortunately, removing ```durationInDays``` did not resolve this. Same Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, in your example, recurrenceSettings is being passed in with the following values:

```
"recurrenceSettings":
    {
        "recurrenceType":"weekly",
        "recurrenceEndType":"occurrences",
        "durationInDays":7,
        "recurrenceCount":3
    },
    "autoReviewSettings":{
        "notReviewedResult":"Approve"
    }
```

There are limits to the duration in days that one can specify for recurring reviews:

```
weekly ->   6
monthly -> 27
quarterly -> 80
annual -> 360
```

The durationInDays value that you’re passing for recurrenceType weekly is greater than the allowed maximum(6). Please try setting a value less than 7.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that changing the durationInDays value to 6 works. I will build in a check that verifies the durationInDays is within an acceptable range